# Retraining with the same test data returns different accuracies

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I am using Pytorch for training my vit-3d model on my data. I have designed my cross-validation function and trained the model. While running the code file, I am getting different test accuracies each time which range from 79-84.7% (which is scaring me). I have used the seed() function and also tried to initialize the weights of the above model, but there is significantly no change in the behavior.
Please suggest me.